# How to programmatically close QMenu

Tags: qt, user-interface, qdialog, qmenu

I have pretty specific situation. I want to place a `QAction` into `QToolbar` and reach following behaviour:

1. Checkable `QAction` with icon.
2. Classic arrow on the right side which is used for showing menu
3. By pressing this arrow my `QDialog` should appears on screen instead of `QMenu`-like one

Now I'm a bit confused with implementing all this things together.


For now I've created `QAction` added it to toolbar and also created an empty `QMenu`because I didn't get the idea of how to add the "dropdown" arrow another way.

So, I also connected my slot to `QMenu` `aboutToShow()` signal and now, I can create my dialog and `exec()` it just before `QMenu` shows. But here's the main problem appears: after I did everything with my dialog an click `OK` button `QMenu` trying to appear, but as it is empty it shows nothing and further actions become available only after I left-click somwhere to "close" this menu.


Is there any way to force `QMenu` not to show or can inherit from `QMenu` and reimplemnt its behaviour (I've tried to do such trick with `exec()` `show()` `popup()` methods of `QMenu` after subclassing from it, but none of them are being called when menu appears on the screen) ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's the solution, which worked for me.

```
class QCustomMenu : public QMenu
{
  Q_OBJECT
public:
  QCustomMenu(QObject *parent = 0):QMenu(parent){};
};
```

In code:

```
QAction* myActionWithMenu = new QAction ( "ActionText", toolbar);
QCustomMenu* myMenu = new QCustomMenu(toolbar);
connect(myMenu, SIGNAL(aboutToShow()), this, SLOT(execMyMenu()));
```

`execMyMenu()` implementation:

```
void execMyMenu(){
  m_activeMenu = (QCustomMenu*)sender(); // m_activeMenu -- private member of your head class, needs to point to active custom menu
  QMyDialog* dlg = new QMyDialog();
  // setup your dialog with needed information
  dlg->exec();
  // handle return information
  m_myTimer = startTimer(10); // m_myTimer -- private member of your head(MainWindow or smth like that) class
}
```

Now we have to handle timerEvent and close our menu:

```
void MyHeadClass::timerEvent(QTimerEvent *event)
{
    // Check if it is our "empty"-menu timer 
    if ( event->timerId()==m_myTimer )
    {
        m_activeMenu->close(); // closing empty menu
        killTimer(m_myTimer);  // deactivating timer
        m_myTimer = 0;         // seting timer identifier to zero
        m_activeMenu = NULL;   // as well as active menu pointer to NULL
    }
}
```

It works great on every platform and does what I wanted. 
Hope, this would help someone. I've spent week trying to find this solution.

Comment: You have memory leak there. You must call `QMenu( parent )` in your constructor initialization.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I absolutely forgot abou this thing

Comment: @SaZ strange things happening now: in Windows it works perfect, but under the Linux closing menu-dialog causes all toolbar to freeze. May be I've forgot something?